# nmle:gls with AR or MA terms

Tags: r, arima, generalized-least-squares

I am using nlme:gls to model trends. My understanding is that including AR or MA terms allows the model the correlation structure of the residuals rather than affecting the the regression estimates. Indeed, running a model with or without a correlation structure leads (in my case) to similar results.

I also noticed that the MA and AR terms are not included in the regression model as such and indeed including a term or not does not change the number of degrees of freedom.

```
mod.gls = gls(fconvictDiff ~ tfrDiff+policyDiff-1, data = data,
              method="ML", na.action=na.omit)

mod.gls = gls(fconvictDiff ~ tfrDiff+policyDiff-1, data = data,
              correlation=corARMA(p=1), method="ML", na.action=na.omit)
```

Could anyone say a bit more on how the MA and AR terms are modelled and how to best report (if necessary) in a write up?

Thanks!

Comment: A good place to start would be the [corARMA  documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/nlme/man/corARMA.html) and references therein.

Comment: Thanks @dipetkov I must admit I am still not clear from the documentation how they are modelled. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the references listed in the documentation- could you point me to free resources?

Comment: I apologize that I didn't think about access. There is Cross Validated itself of course. About forecasting, see [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/). Parts of the Pinheiro and Bates book are available in Google Books [here](https://books.google.ca/books?ei=PBB2T67wN6X20gH7zLzPDQ&id=y54QDUTmvDcC&dq=pinheiro+bates&q=crossed&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: One question you might want to answer for yourself is why jump into complex correlation structure straight away. You can learn about other covariance structures [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html).